# Loading Indicator on Synchronous Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, loading, synchronous

I'm using ajax with jQuery on my site and need to show a progress  / loading indicator.

My dilemna is this:

- Synchronous AJAX locks the browser, so I cant do anything (e.g. show a loading indicator) till the contents are returned, by which time it is too late
- I am using JSON as the return data type and setting async = true returns an empty response string
- my whole framework relies on the return type being JSON-formatted

I cannot seem to find any way to get JS to give the user an indication that something is in progress, except for doing an alert(). (For some reason an alert does work).

Any suggestions?

My code:

JS

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: url, 
cache: false,
    data: params, // array of parameters
    async: false, // responseText is empty if set to true
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function()
    {
        alert("Ajax post request to the following script failed: " + url);
    }

} ); 

var html = jqXHR.responseText;
```

PHP

```
$return = array();
$return['status'] = 1;
$return['message'] = "some html here ...";
echo json_encode($return);
```

Answer (score 20):

You need to show a loading display before calling the ajax request
and you can use the callback function and `success` to hide a loading display

```
  //show here the loading display
  $(".loading").show();
  setTimeout(function() {
    var jqXHR = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url, 
        cache: false,
        data: params, // array of parameters
        async: false, // responseText is empty if set to true
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(){
               alert("Ajax post request to the following script failed: " + url);
        },
         success: function(){
              //hide loading display here
               $(".loading").hide();
        }
    }); 
  }, 0);
```

well you need a delay using `setTimeout()` before calling the ajax function because it can even halt the display of the loading display because as while `$(".loading").show();` is being animated the sync ajax request will be called and will surely lock the browser before the loading display animation will be completed

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, however I get an empty response text as the rest of the code seems to run, attempt to grab response text from an ajax function that hasnt yet run, and fails. it's unfortunately not practical to setTimeout on all my other code, as the code that grabs the responseText is throughout the system ...

Comment: well, i ended up using a timeout and patching all my code, and it works nicely. so thanks for giving me a prod to get me there (would vote you up, but dont have enough reputation points!)

Comment: I think timeout will make the ajax call asynchronous.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the Jquery Global Ajax Event Handlers. This link describes them in detail:

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $("#loading").show();
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $("#loading").hide();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. doesnt work sadly, it appears the DOM changes are only applied once the function completes (by which time it's too late ...)

Comment: the first function in code may be `$(document).ajaxSend(function() { ...`

Answer (score 2):

Hi use some thing like that to get a post in magento....

This is the html

```
    <div class="popupNews">
    <div class="popClose">X</div>
        <div id="loading"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/loader.gif'); ?>" border="0" /></div>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this the jquery

```
    var url = 'http://blabla.com/ajax';

jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend:function(){
        jQuery("#loading").show();
    },
    complete:function(){
        jQuery("#loading").hide();
    }
});

jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {id: post},
    success: function(data) {
        jQuery("#result").html(data);
    }
});
```