# Show wait screen for ajax calls which have async = false

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have some functionality where Ajax calls are being made with async=false. I am using following code

```
  $(document).ajaxSend(function (event, request, settings) {
            $("#__smoke_screen").show();
        });
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
            $("#__smoke_screen").hide();
        });
```

To show waiting screen but it does not work for sync call. Is there any way I can show any kind of waiting message for sync calls.

PS: I can't to async=true.

Thanks

Comment: First off synchronous ajax calls are a horrible user experience.  You should probably redesign to make them async.  Second off, all you have to do for a wait msg during a sync ajax is put up the message before you call the ajax call and then pull it down after the ajax call.  You can literally just make your own function that puts it up, executes the ajax call, then pulls it down.  It's synchronous so the ajax call just becomes a plain function call.

Comment: Why would you say you can't do async?  It's just a matter of proper code design to do async ajax.

Comment: A suggestion: when showing a smoke screen or other "please wait" screen, count the number of "show_please_wait" requests and don't hide the screen until the same number of "hide_please_wait" requests have been received.  This helps to avoid a situation where you make two async calls in a row, the first one completes and hides the screen, and the second is still running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is single threaded meaning that while the thread of control is doing something like waiting (eg. for an Ajax response), nothing else can happen.  This includes redrawing and updating the screen.  The best you could do would be to open a dialog BEFORE you make the Ajax call, wait for the dialog to be shown (by some kind of callback event) and then make your synchronous Ajax call.  When the call returns, dispose of the dialog.  However, during your Ajax call wait, the screen will not be repainted nor respond to any user interactions.  Synchronous Ajax calls really have to be extremely quick or avoided completely.

If your synchronous Ajax call takes time, then it is highly likely that there is something wrong in the design.

See also the following related Q&A:

- [Loading Indicator on Synchronous Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599915/loading-indicator-on-synchronous-ajax)

Comment: I just want to point out that synchronous AJAX is not the only reason to need this.  In my case, I am updating options after a highcharts is rendered, and the update takes about 20s for large charts - it's nice to be able to show our users that something is indeed happening when they click the "show all data points" button.  This solution with the callbacks helps tremendously!