# why loader image is not showing?

Tags: jquery, .when

I am having a function which take some time to complete it's process. So I am planning to display the process image until it's going to finish.

Please take a look at the sample here.when the user clicks on the button process will start. Here I put setTimeout function to make delay.But the processing image is not showing.

[Sample Code](https://jsfiddle.net/3espztjw/4/)

If I am placing the code for hiding the image inside setTimeout function it is working.

But in actual code that is also not working.

Also I tried with

```
$.when($("#loaderImg").show()).done(function(){
showSomeProcess()
$("#loaderImg").hide();
})
```

So please help me with this sample code. I dont understand why the processing image is not showing.

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599915/loading-indicator-on-synchronous-ajax/16600345#16600345

Comment: @user1490835 it is not related with Ajax.

Comment: Demo works fine. What does your actual code do? provide a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl sorry....that is I tried to make work. Please check the updated one.

Comment: What update? Put all relevant code in the question itself. Questions should be self contained and demos used only to support what actually exists in the question itself. Hard to make any sense out of what your problem really is

Comment: @svk Actually its showing the processing image and instantly hiding it

Comment: @Ninja for me it is not at all showing. Any reason why it is not waiting till the process is completed.

Comment: @svk If you put debugger statement just after $("#loaderImg").show() in your code, there you can see processing image. And its getting hidden in the when block because its not waiting for any promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of promise will solve your problem. Updated fiddle also https://jsfiddle.net/3espztjw/5/

```
$("#startProcess").click(function(){
    $("#loaderImg").show();
    $.when(showSomeProcess()).then(function(){
        $("#loaderImg").hide();  
    })
});
var showSomeProcess=function(){
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred()
    $("#progress").html("Process started");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#progress").html("Process end");
        deferred.resolve();
    },3000);
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the `setTimeout()` function does not execute in flow. It breaks the synchronous sequence. This does not mean it is asynchronous and running on separate thread. It just executes it outside the sequential order. So the `hide()` function executes before the task is actually completed and we don't see the loader.

It is asynchronous(partially) but definitely not running on concurrent thread.

So, something like this code wont actually work as expected:

```
$("#loaderImg").show();
    setTimeout(function(){
       $("#progress").html("Process end");
    },3000);
$("#loaderImg").hide();
```

The hide function will be triggered before 3 secs are completed.

This may help if you want to hide the loader after 3secs:

```
$("#loaderImg").show();
   setTimeout(function(){
      $("#progress").html("Process end");
      $("#loaderImg").hide(); 
   },3000);
```

Also, just because `setTimeout()` runs out of sync with the sequence doesn't mean it improves performance because its running on the same thread.

An example which does not work as expected:

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').html("Started");
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('div').html("Working");
  },3000);
  $('div').html("Finished");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
</div>
```

Surely you can notice how the sequence goes in the above snippet.

Some working code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').html("Started");
  $('div').html("Working");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('div').html("Finished");
  }, 3000);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
</div>
```