# JQuery loader with AJAX working async:false

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm a newcomer to the jquery planet and I have no idea how to solve my problem. I have read all the answers to similar questions but none of them work for me. I work on MAC OS X and therefore Safari with JQuery 2.1.1, but in the end my platform will be shared online and must be compatible with other browsers.

**PURPOSE:** I would like to display a page containing my loading animation. however my JQuery function contains an ajax executable with `async:false` mode to be able to return the executed script's response. So I can't use the `beforeSend` and `complete` options. I tried to use a solution that I found on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599915/loading-indicator-on-synchronous-ajax). Unfortunately my animation is not displayed

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myRun" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ... SOME ACTIONs ...
    <input class="demo" type="button" id="runner" value="Submit">
</form>
<div class="preloader" id="run_loader"><?php include('map/run_loader.php');?></div>
```

**JS**:

```
// Run platform
$('#runner').click(function() {
  $('#run_loader').show();
  setTimeout(function() {
      var results = function(){
        $.ajax({
          url : "php/runner.php",
          type: "post",
          global: false,
          async:false,
          data : $("#myRun").serializeArray(),
          success: function (response) {
            //alert(response);
            //window.location.href = response; *** DOESN'T WORK HERE ***
            $('#run_loader').hide();
            res = response;
          }
        });
        return res;
      }();
  }, 0);
  window.location.href = String(results);
});
```

**QUESTION(s):** Could you help me to run this loading page? Do you have any other comments about my code to improve myself?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is entirely caused by the use of `async: false`. The reason is because this stops the browser UI from updating while the request is in progress, leading users to believe the browser has crashed or hung. As such, it's a very bad practice which should never be used unless there is absolutely no alternative. If you check the console you'll even see the browser warning you not to use synchronous calls.

The assertion in your comment that `window.location.href` doesn't work in the `success` handler is false, it will work fine. If it's not working for you then there is an error being returned from the server side code to your AJAX call which you need to investigate and debug.

To improve your JS logic you should use the async callback pattern more effectively, by performing all logic that depends on the result of the AJAX call *within* the `success` event handler. You also don't need the timeout either. Try this:

```js
$('#runner').click(function() {
  $('#run_loader').show();

  $.ajax({
    url: "php/runner.php",
    type: "post",
    data: $("#myRun").serializeArray(),
    success: function(response) {
      $('#run_loader').hide();
      window.location.assign(response);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Powerful !!! You save my life. Many thanks :). But why this `async:false` is a very bad practices if it is proposed?

Comment: No problem, glad to help. It's a bit like `eval()` in that it exists, but there are *a lot* of much better ways of doing what you need.